# How to handle a triggered subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a Service:

```
export class TabTitleService extends Title {

         titleSubject = new Subject();

setTitle(newTitle: string) {

    this.titleSubject.pipe(
        debounceTime(2000),
    ).subscribe( (title: string) => {
        super.setTitle(title);
    });


      this.titleSubject.next(newTitle);
    }
}
```

I have provided this service in a some components.

And with this code i am changing the Title every time i switch the view with 2 seconds of debounce.
And this is the result i wanna get, but the problem is: I wanna do the same thing but i dont wanna make a new subscription every time the view is changed or the method is called. I want to listen to the same Subscription every time the method is called, and not create a new one every time the method is called

Comment: If i understand well i think you're looking for shareReplay operator https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it in this way: create a component that handles the subscription and each component update the title from the service. Like this:

#### TabTitleService

```
export class TabTitleService extends Title {
  
public title$: Subject<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.title$ = new Subject();
  }

  public changeTitle(title: string): void {
    this.title$.next(title);
  }
}
```

#### TabTitleComponent

This component is created to retrieve and render your title (but you can retrieve the title wherever you want).

```
export class TabTitleComponent {
  public title: string;

  constructor(
    private readonly tabTitleService: TabTitleService
  ) {
     tabTitleService.title$.subscribe(title => this.title = title);
  }
}
```

#### OtherComponent

This component will update your title

```
export class YourComponent {
  
  constructor(private readonly tabTitleService: TabTitleService) {
     tabTitleService.changeTitle("Your title");  
  }
}
```

In this way, you have a service that handles the `subject`, and each component can update the title. On the other hand, the component that draws the title retrieves the new title and updates the subject.

Comment: i need it to acomplish this only in this method, beacuse i have 30+ components that use this

Comment: I need the service and that method to handle this